# How to get index of matching element in playwright?

Tags: node.js, playwright

For example I have something like this:

[image]

I'd like to know the index of `div[@data-filled]` which `data-filled` attribute is true.

Answer (score 1):

As of Feb 19th, this does not seem to be possible.
The given workaround is iterating the children, checking for a match and then returning the index.
See: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/11909